# Really simple custom shader in Three.js - how to make it work?

Tags: shader, webgl, three.js, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm trying to make the simplest custom shader for Three.js that I can, but I haven't figured out how to make it work.  The object the I'm using the shader for doesn't appear at all.

In my page html I have:

```
<script id="simplefs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<script id="simplevs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = modelViewMatrix * projectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
</script>
```

Then in javascript:

```
var vertShader = document.getElementById("simplevs").innerHTML;
var fragShader = document.getElementById("simplefs").innerHTML;

var myMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader : vertShader,
    fragmentShader: fragShader
});

var baseBevel = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(BaseRadius - BaseBevel, BaseRadius, BaseBevel, 100, 100, false),
                               myMaterial )
baseBevel.position.x = x;
baseBevel.position.y = y;
baseBevel.position.z = BaseHeight - (BaseBevel / 2.0);
baseBevel.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2.0;

scene.add(baseBevel);
```

Where the object should be, there is nothing. It works fine if I replace the material with a `MeshLambertMaterial`.  What am I missing that I need to make it work?

Answer (score 7):

Easy solution, the order of the matrix multiplication in the vertex shader needs to be changed to:

```
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
```